# Makefile causes `gfortran: error: No such file or directory`

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile this code with gfortran.

Makefile:

```
# makefile for BIRRP

FC = gfortran
FCFLAGS = -g -fbounds-check
FLFLAGS = -g -fbacktrace
SRC = birrp.f  coherence.f  dataft.f  diagnostic.f  fft.f  filter.f  math.f  rarfilt.f  response.f  rtpss.f  utils.f  weight.f  zlinpack.f

# "make" builds all

PROGRAM = birrp
all: $(PROGRAM)
$(PROGRAM): $(SRC)
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) $@ $<

%.o: %.f
    $(FC) $(FLFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

It doesn't work

```
gfortran -g -fbounds-check birrp birrp.f
gfortran: error: birrp: No such file or directory
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'birrp' failed
make: *** [birrp] Error 1
```

I am using the gfortran compiler. I have copied the Makefile from my other program.

---

After adding `-o`:

```
FC = gfortran
FCFLAGS = -g -c -fbounds-check
FLFLAGS = -g -fbacktrace
SRC = birrp.f coherence.f dataft.f diagnostic.f fft.f filter.f math.f rarfilt.f response.f rtpss.f utils.f weight.f zlinpack.f

# "make" builds all

PROGRAM = birrp
all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(SRC)
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.f
    $(FC) $(FLFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Now it just compiles

```
        gfortran -g -c -fbounds-check -o birrp birrp.f
```

Why?

Comment: Your compile line does not include an output target.  It should read : gfortran -g -fbounds-check -o birrp birrp.f

Comment: @P.Hinker How to change my makefile?

Comment: Your edit materially changes the problem and invalidates a given answer. I don't think that's a valid edit. You should probably accept the given answer and file a new question with the updated makefile.

Comment: That said your new problem is, essentially, a typo. You used `$<` which means the first prerequisite where you meant `$^` which means *all* the prerequisites. See [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gfortran` interprets *birrp* as a source-file, but you want it as the `outfile`.

```
man gfortran
```

says the `outfile` is specified by the `-o` parameter, so your target becomes this:

```
$(PROGRAM): $(SRC)
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

But this doesn't solve all your problems. According to the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$<` specifies the **first dependency** and not all of them. You always want to have the whole list of dependencies, which would be `$^`.

So your target becomes this:

```
$(PROGRAM): $(SRC)
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```